# php date format string customizing

Tags: php, date

what I got here:

```
<?php echo stripslashes($row['date']); ?>
```

I want to customize how the date is displayed like:

```
date("l, F jS Y");
```

I know there's a way to do it inside that string rather than doing it in the database, would any of you happen to know?

Comment: Is date a timestamp, datetime, or date field type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Use the second parameter for `date()` combined with `strtotime()`: `date("l, F jS Y", strtotime(stripslashes($row['date']));`

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin: From where does JavaScript come into the picture?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: Could you post the solutions for us to expand our knowledge?